# OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ not referencing tiles correctly

Tags: openlayers-2, tiles, mbtiles, zxy

I have tiles stored here:

../CO_054/MtViewBaseMap/MtViewBaseTiles

in the order : C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.10.3\webapps\CO_054\MtViewBaseMap\MtViewBaseTiles\0\0\0.png

I'm using this to reference the tiles:

```
 var tiles = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ(
           "CO_054",
           [
            "../CO_054/MtViewBaseMap/MtViewBaseTiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"
           ],
           {
            attribution: "Data copyright OpenStreetMap contributors",
            sphericalMercator: true,
            wrapDateLine: true,
            numZoomLevels: 18
           }
         );
        map.addLayer(tiles);
```

However, I only get broken image icons and the following errors:

```
  HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /CO_054/MtViewBaseMap/MtViewBaseTiles/11/1025/1021.png. Reason:

    Not Found
Powered by Jetty://
```

I can see that the directory is not being constructed correctly but it seems that my code is set up to match where the .png files live. I mimicked this from another html file with the same file structure and it works fine.

At CO_054/MtViewBaseMap/MtViewBaseTiles/11/ I have a folder named 329 and two .png files (793.png and 794.png). Why is the WMS looking for 1023/1023.png?

This is what it should be reading:

[image]

Here's what the directory looks like in z = 11:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order for GeoServer to serve static files you need to place them in the `www` folder of the `data` directory. So your path should be:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.10.3\webapps\geoserver\data\www\CO_054\Mt_ViewBaseLayer\0\0\0.png
```

Comment: placed the files in the folder you specified and still got the same error. in the developer console I get this message: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/GeoServer%202.10.3/webapps/data/www/Mt_ViewBaseLayer/11/1025/1024.png

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to be using Jetty or tomcat to make this work

Comment: I am using jetty

Comment: then your URL above would be http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www/Mt_.... not file:///.....

Comment: changed it to this: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/www/CO_054/Mt_View/Mt_ViewBaseLayer/${z}/${x}/${y}.png" Now the message says "GET: then the pathway with the wrong indexed pngs

Comment: this is an indexing error. For some reason the openlayers.xyz method is not reading the directories correctly: http://localhost:8080/CO_054/MtViewBaseMap/MtViewBaseTiles/11/1025/1021.png  there is no 11/1025/1021.png that was created by mbtiles. 11 is the zoom level the map opens to. From here, shouldn't it be reading the tiles stored in the 11 folder? This is driving me crazy.